# Make a service close an external activity (created through implicit intent)

Tags: android, service, android-activity

What I want to do is quite simple: my application offers the user to watch a maximum of 10 min of video, then it stops the video and gets back to my application (previous activity). The video is shown in an external player with that code:

```
Intent intentVideo = new Intent();
intentVideo.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentVideo.setData(Uri.parse(url)));
startActivity(intentVideo);
```

Then a background `Service` check periodically if time is elapsed or not.

How can my service kill the video activity (**where I can't add code or listeners, or whatever, because it is provided by an external app**) and make my app go back to its previous activity when time is elapsed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to define a `BroadcastReceiver` inside the `Activity`. When the `Service` needs to notify the `Activity` that the time is up, send a broadcast and receive it in the `BroadcastReceiver`. Then, inside the `onReceive()` call `finish()` on the `Activity` to kill it. Hope this helps.

Comment: When you say "BroadcastReceiver inside the Activity", what Activity are you talking about? Because the foreground activity is the video player so I can't change the code to add a BroadcastReceiver. If I add a BroadcastReceiver in the previous activity I guess it won't receive anything as it this activity is not displayed anymore?

Comment: Flox what Egor said was an exact answer , What do u mean by cant add a code in your app ,that doesnt make sense

Comment: I don't understand how and where am I supposed to call finish(). The BroadcastReceiver isn't it supposed to be in the foreground activity which is the video player activity (external app) ? Because the activity that runs the video activity (and therefore that can stop it) is paused. I guess Broadcast receinving don't work in Pause state?

Comment: @Flox, BroadcastReceiver will work even when the enclosing Activity is in background. BroadcastReceiver can easily be a separate class, but designing it as an inner class of the Activity makes it easy to access the Activity within the onReceive() and call finish() on the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Okay here's my final code if it can help, thanks to Egor.

Note: Two solution are possible to force stopping the player activity:

1. using `startActivityForResult(intent, rq)` / `finishActivity(rq)`
2. using  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

Be careful using `finishActivity()`, some external apps won't close because of their behavior. For me it worked well when I open videos using VLC player, but not working when I open videos with Dailymotion app.

*ActivityThatLaunchesPlayer.java*

```
public class ActivityThatLaunchesPlayer extends Activity 
{

    private BroadcastReceiver brdreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            System.out.println("broadcast signal received");

             //either
             finishActivity(57); //57 is my arbitrary requestcode

             //or either :
            Intent intentback = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  ActivityThatLaunchesPlayer.class);
            intentback.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intentback); 
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //set the brdcstreceiver to listen to the slot
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(brdreceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.portail10.timeElapsed"));

            //here we launch the player (android opens a new appropriate activity)
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 57); //again arbitrary rqstcode

            //here we start the service that watch the time elapsed watching the video
            intentServ = new Intent(this, TimeWatcher.class);
            startService(intentServ);
     }
}
```

*TimeWatcher.java*

```
public class TimeWatcher extends Service 
{

    //... some code is missing, but the main idea is here

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            //send the broadcast when time's up
            Intent intentbrd = new Intent();
            intentbrd.setAction("com.example.portail10.timeElapsed");
            sendBroadcast(intentbrd); 

            System.out.println("Brdcast sent");

            stopSelf();

        }
    }, 0, 600000); //in ms = 10min

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't work for me. The Player is never executed.